# Modular functions and modular forms

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, modular-forms

A modular form of weight $k$ as a **holomorphic** function satisfying $f(\gamma z)=(cz+d)^kf(z)$ (automorphy relation of weight $k$) on the upper-half plane and also **holomorphic** at cusps.

A modular function as a **meromorphic** function satisfying $f(\gamma z)=f(z)$ (automorphy relation of weight $0$) and **meromorphic** at cusps.

Apparently, a quotient of two modular forms of the same weight is a modular function. Is the a modular functions always a quotient of two modular forms of the same weight?

It is definitely the case for $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ as we have the $j$-invariant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result is true for modular functions of level $\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is any finite-index subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (or, more generally, any discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ of finite covolume).

The proof is as follows. Let $Y$ be the quotient $\Gamma \backslash \mathcal{H}$. Then $Y$ is a (non-compact) Riemann surface, and there is a compact Riemann surface $X = Y \cup \{cusps\}$ given by adjoining finitely many cusps to $Y$. For simplicity I'm going to suppose $\Gamma$ has no elements of finite order (this is not needed but makes life easier).

Let $f$ be a modular function. Then $f$ is a meromorphic function on $X$, so it has finitely many poles, say $p_1, \dots, p_n$, with degrees $d_1, \dots, d_n$.

Clearly, it suffices to show that we can find a nonzero modular form $g$ (of some large weight $k \gg 0$) which vanishes at each $p_i$ with degree $\ge d_i$, because then $h = f \times g$ is also a modular form, and thus $f = h / g$ is a ratio of modular forms.

Now, let $M_k(\Gamma)$ be the space of weight $k$ modular forms of level $\Gamma$; and for each $i$, consider the linear map $L_i : M_k(\Gamma) \to \mathbb{C}^{d_i}$ which pulls out the first $d_i$ terms of the Taylor expansion of $g$ at $p_i$. Concatenating together the $L_i$ I get one big linear map $L : M_k(\Gamma) \to \mathbb{C}^d$, where $d = \sum d_i$; and we want to show that this map has **non-zero kernel**.

However, the dimension of $M_k(\Gamma)$ goes to $\infty$ with $k$. So eventually there must be something nontrivial in the kernel and we're done.

Answer (score 1):

This is true for modular forms over $\Gamma_0(N)$. There, the story is that the field of modular functions is given by $\mathbb{C}(j(z), j(Nz))$.

But "all" modular forms is a potentially very big family of things, including forms that don't live on $\Gamma_0(N)$. For example, I have no idea whether the analogous result is true for modular functions over a noncongruence subgroup.

Comment: Let's just consider congruence subgroups. I think in my book, we define those notions only for congruence subgroups.